# draw multiple lines for timeplot in R using ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a dataframe in R. First column is date. The rest columns are data for each category.

```
library(tidyverse)

mydf <- tribble(~Date, ~View1, ~View2, ~View3, ~View4, ~View5, ~View6,
        '2010-05-17', 13, 10, 13, 10, 13, 10,
        '2010-05-18', 11, 11, 13, 10, 13, 10,
        '2010-05-19',  4, 12, 13, 10, 13, 10,
        '2010-05-20',  2, 10, 13, 10, 13, 10,
        '2010-05-21', 23, 16, 13, 10, 13, 10,
        '2010-05-22', 26, 15, 13, 10, 13, 10
        )
```

How can plot a timeplot with two lines? Each line for each column. i.e one line for View1, one line for View2, one line for View3 and so on. The x-axis is Date. Is there a function in ggplot can achieve this easily?

I searched other posts, see a solution below, but it gives me nothing on the plot.

```
mydf %>% 
  gather(key,value, View1, View2, View3, View4, View5, View6 )  %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x=Date, y=value, colour=key))
```

I also tried the commands below.

```
test_data_long1 <- melt(mydf, id="Date") 
ggplot(data=test_data_long1,
       aes(x=date, y=value, colour=variable)) +
       geom_line()
```

It gives me an error.

```
Don't know how to automatically pick scale for object of type function. Defaulting to continuous.
Error: All columns in a tibble must be 1d or 2d objects:
* Column `x` is function
```

Comment: `date` should be `Date`

Comment: and the first attempt is missing a `geom_line()`

Answer (score 0):

A couple of ways...

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

mydf %>% 
  mutate(Date = as.Date(Date)) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = Date)) +
  geom_line(aes(y = View1), colour = 'red') +
  geom_line(aes(y = View2), colour = 'blue')


mydf %>% 
  mutate(Date = as.Date(Date)) %>% 
  gather(-Date, key = 'View', value = 'value' )   %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x=Date, y=value, colour=View)) +
    geom_line()
```